# Replace multiple IDs within text expression

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have checked and I haven't found a question like this before.

I have a table called `tests` which (simplified) contain 3 columns.

```
 |  id  |  name  |      expression      |
=========================================
 |  1   |  width |                      |
 |  2   | length |                      |
 |  3   |  area  |  [1] * [2]           |
```

I need a query which given a test ID can return the fully qualified expression, that is replace the ID numbers within the expression with the related names.

The expression will always have the ID numbers within square brackets.

I have followed several paths but this is my current query but it doesn't replace the names into one string.

Query:

```
WITH regexmatch AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    expression,
    (regexp_matches(expression, '\[(\d+)\]', 'g'))[1] AS replaceid
  FROM
    test
  WHERE
    expression IS NOT NULL
  AND
    id = 3
  GROUP BY
    id, expression
)
SELECT
  regexmatch.id,
  regexmatch.expression,
  REPLACE(regexmatch.expression, replaceid, (SELECT name FROM test WHERE id = replaceid::bigint))
FROM
  regexmatch
```

Output:

```
 |  id  |  expression  |      replacement      |
================================================
 |  1   |  [1] * [2]   |  [width] * [2]        |
 |  2   |  [1] * [2]   |  [1] * [length]       |
```

Is this query possible and if so how should I go about doing it?

Comment: The correct solution is to use a recursive CTE along with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is recursive common table expression:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT, "name" VARCHAR(100), expression VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO test(id,  "name", expression)
SELECT 1,  'width', NULL                      
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'length', NULL                      
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'area'  ,  '[1] * [2]' 
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'height', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'volume', '[3] * [4]'       
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'volumne_alt', '[2]^3';
```

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id,  expression::varchar(10000), "name"
         ,(regexp_matches(expression, '\[(\d+)\]'))[1] AS repid
  FROM  test
  WHERE expression IS NOT NULL  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, REPLACE(expression, repid, (SELECT name 
                                         FROM test 
                                         WHERE id = repid::int))::varchar(10000)
          ,"name",(regexp_matches(expression, '\[(\d+)\]'))[1]    
  FROM cte c
  WHERE c.expression ~ '(.*)\[(\d+)\](.*)'
)
SELECT id, "name", expression
FROM cte
WHERE expression !~ '(.*)\[(\d+)\](.*)'
ORDER BY id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dd2fa/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ id  ║    name      ║     expression     ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣
║  3  ║ area         ║ [width] * [length] ║
║  5  ║ volume       ║ [area] * [height]  ║
║  6  ║ volumne_alt  ║ [length]^3         ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

---

With table `UPDATE`:

```
WITH cte AS
(...
)
UPDATE test AS t
SET expression = c.expression
FROM cte AS c
WHERE t.id = c.id AND c.expression !~ '(.*)\[(\d+)\](.*)';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dd2fa/9/1)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ id  ║    name      ║     expression     ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1  ║ width        ║ (null)             ║
║  2  ║ length       ║ (null)             ║
║  3  ║ area         ║ [width] * [length] ║
║  4  ║ height       ║ (null)             ║
║  5  ║ volume       ║ [area] * [height]  ║
║  6  ║ volumne_alt  ║ [length]^3         ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝
```